# what's difference between configuration and interface in USB device?

Tags: interface, configuration, usb

What's the difference between `configuration` and `interface` in USB devices?

I appreciate if you explain it for me by an example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A USB device has a certain number of configurations.  The USB host must tell the device which configuration to use as one of the last steps needed to set it up.

Each configuration has different power requirements and a different set of interfaces that are exposed.  You can think of an interface as a function or a feature of the device.  One interface might be an HID keyboard, and another interface might be a virtual serial USB CDC ACM serial port.  Typical USB drivers on the host side will attach themselves to an interface of a device rather than the whole device.

A device with multiple configurations might have a high-power configuration where it provides some interface that needs a lot of power (e.g. one that controls motors from the USB power) and a low-power configuration that just has low-power interfaces.

Every device needs at least one configuration and one interface.  I think that devices with more than one configuration are rare, since you need specialized drivers on the host side to pick the configuration and it's not that useful.  Devices with multiple interfaces are called composite devices, and those are common.

Comment: can we change the setting of the USB descriptors? if possible, which function does this request do?

Comment: where are USB descriptors stored? Do they store in the device firmware?

Comment: They are stored in the device.  Usually you would have to modify the firmware if you want to change them.

Answer (score 1):

From USB Spec Section 9.6.3:
A 'USB' device has one or more configuration (descriptors). Each configuration has one or more interfaces and each interface has zero or more endpoints.